# django controlcenter url name

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

while using `django-controlcenter` package, I am trying to set a url in a html template to access a dashboard.

In my urlpattersn I have:

```
path('admin/dashboard/', controlcenter.urls, name='dashboard'),
```

In my settings, I have a set a dashboard:

```
CONTROLCENTER_DASHBOARDS = (
    ('admindash', 'myapp.dashboards.AdminDashboard'),
)
```

So for a url that normally resolves as `/admin/dashboard/admindash`
, what the template url should be? `django.urls` `include` would not work with the package and the issue would be to register a proper namespace. I directly tried `{% url 'dashboard:admindash' %}` and `{% url 'admindash' %}` but it returned a *NoReverseMatch* error.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to use this code?:

```
{% url 'admindash' %}
```

Answer (score 0):

For url namespace syntax should be `<namespace>:<name>`. But you are using it in wrong order `{% url 'dashboard:admindash' %}`. Which should be `{% url 'admindash:dashboard' %}`

Answer (score 0):

The current solution I came up with is by using a `RedirectView` in urls:

```
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView

urlspattersn=[    
   path('admin/dashboard/', controlcenter.urls),
   path('admin/dashboard/', RedirectView.as_view(url='admindash/', permanent=False), name='admindash'),

]
```

and then calling in template:

```
{% url 'admindash' %}
```